# Exposed filter for file field

Tags: 7, files, views

I have a content type with several file fields. I have a view listing nodes of that content type. Now I want to add an exposed filters for each file field to let users filter only those nodes which have a file attached to corresponding field (or not have, whatever they choose).

So, I see choice options like this:

- Any
- Has file attached
- No file attached

Is there a module for this? Or my only way is to write a custom Views filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering to myself :]

Add a new filter for, say, `field_file:fid`, make it exposed and choose `Is not empty` operator.

It will not work :D It is a [known Views issue](https://drupal.org/node/477984). Luckily, [comment #70](https://drupal.org/node/477984#comment-7343408) in that issue has a patch to fix this operator behavior, apply it and enjoy :)

Comment: Patch works, but you get a strict warning.  :-P  Better than nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work around it using **Grouped filters**.

I added Content File:fid filter and exposed it.

Then I selected Grouped filters option (instead of the Single filter).

In the table that appears where you can set your options, the first one is Any (default), in the second one I added

```
Label YES
Operator Is greater than 
Value 0
```

and I removed the third table row as I didn't need it.

This filter works! It shows the filter with 2 options: Any and YES. Any is default and shows all results. If I select YES it only shows results that have a file attached :)

I also added Content: file among Fields so it's easy to test the filter.

Answer (score 0):

My approach for this was based on experimentation on previous answer by [prkos](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/52224/prkos)

My case included a image field with images uploaded to my site. 
So the file-path output for the field was - http://example.com/sites/default/files/001.png

In the views exposed filter, I have used **File: Path (grouped)** after adding *relationship for file*.

Now for the grouped options

```
- Any -
Yes | Operator: Length is greater than | Value: 0
No  | Operator: is empty (Null)        | Value: NULL
```

This works for me. This gives me a filter for whether an image field is empty or not.

[image]